# Login with Facebook error on iOS 7 app after permission granted

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app just went live on App Store, but some users are experiencing some weird behavior.
It has a 'Login with Facebook' button provided by Facebook SDK for iOS and asks for dozens of permissions.
[image: App Screenshot]

After tapping OK button, it doesn't do anything and stays logged out.
This never happened to me or beta testers, and I know others that downloaded the app from App Store that don't have any problems.

Does anyone have any idea? And why is it user specific error?

I'll post some codes later if there is a need for it.

I properly set the delegate and provide delegate methods!
Thanks For Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem.
Turns out some users didn't have their current password in iOS Settings for Facebook account.
After updating Settings->Facebook->UserAccount->Password with the current one, they all were able to log in in my app! 
Just in case if anyone encounters this.